# Error in Twig template

Tags: php

I am new at twig.
i am trying use twig in my project via composer, but this error occur!

> file_get_contents(App/Views/Home/index.html.twig): failed to open stream: No such file or directory'  Stack trace:'C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php'on line131

everyone can help me?

Comment: Are you sure  about the Path: `App/Views/Home/index.html.twig`? That is: is that Path Correct? Did You try the absolute path as well? From the Error Message; the Path doesn't seem just right.

Comment: yes i am sure that is right.

Comment: now that i am look at that error, i guess maybe it is not correct

Comment: Check again with the absolute path, pretty sure that's the issue here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from compiling your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: i used composer for install twig. am i use any special thing to run it correctly? like a code or more command